# Library preprocessor macros not found in consumer project

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have an old `.a` library called `BULib` with a macro `NEW_API` defined in the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` of the library target. This macro is used inside the lib to expose some methods in the headers or not with conditional compiling. For example:

```
#ifdef NEW_API
+ (nullable NSString *)user;
#endif
```

The problem appears when using this library inside a project. When I want to use

```
[BULib user];
```

I get a compile time error

> No known class method for selector 'getUser'

The problem is solved if I add `NEW_API` in the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` of the project, then I can use the symbol and it works as expected.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the use of the macros between libraries and consumer project but I don't want that behavior.

Why do I have to set the macro in the consumer project if the lib has been compiled correctly with the macro set? If this is not the way to achieve this, what is it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you state which of the quoted code parts occur in which file? I suspect that the API header for your lib contains them or part of them. If the lib defines certain functions, but the header only provides declarations for them in case the switch is defined.... then you need the switch. I know a [mcve] is not easy with the lib, but try to give more information "around" your code quotes please, something of a "**M**almost**C**notreally**VE**".

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions:

1. Add `NEW_API` in `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` as you did
2. Delete `#ifdef NEW_API` and `#end`
3. Use `#define NEW_API` before importing libs header
4. Add `+ (nullable NSString *)user;` and other missing methods in `BULib`'s category

Personally I prefer 3rd option.
It will be something like that:

```
#define NEW_API
#import <bulib.h>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a little bit more the option #3? Thank you!